# Calling a python function from MATLAB, generates an object with only some attribute

Tags: matlab, python-3.x, oop

From MATLAB I am calling a Python function that creates and returns a Python object `MyPyObj` created by me with some attribute. The object is correctly returned however some attribute is missing and when I try to access them in MATLAB, a `No appropriate method, property, or field` error is returned. Does someone know why this happens?

Comment: Can you show your Python code and your MATLAB code?

Comment: Read what a [mcve] is, so we can better help.

Comment: The code is very complex and I cannot simply post it. Moreover generating a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example, would require too much time, again for the code complexity. I rather hope that someone here experienced the same problem, with a similar setting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem following this [post](https://it.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/270805-python-language-in-matlab-no-appropriate-method-property-or-field). Basically I needed to use

```
py.getattr(myPyObj, 'name_of_the_hidden_attribute')
```

However I am still not able to understand why `myPyObj.name_of_the_hidden_attribute` throws an error. I want to provide also this [link](https://it.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/limitations-to-python-support.html) in case my solution does not fix the problem for other users.

Answer (score 0):

Have you already tried [this](https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/153867-running-python-script-in-matlab):

```
commandStr = 'python /Users/myName/pathToScript/sqr.py 2';
[status, commandOut] = system(commandStr);
if status==0
    fprintf('squared result is %d\n',str2num(commandOut));
end
```

Comment: The OP isn't talking about calling Python from the command line. They are talking about using MATLAB's [python interface](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/call-python-from-matlab.html)